# jquery hidden form required field

Tags: jquery, magento

I created registration form for 2 types of reg (private and school) i created forms for all types in one page and 2 radiobuttons .
when user change private reg than forms for school reg hidden via jquery and show privat reg forms. 
But when i tried to register as private  and filled all fields i saw error "Email required" 
I think because another form for school reg (with unfilled field "email") is hidden . 
How can i fix this problem ? Thanks

example of field for email in forms for school and privat registration

```
    <li>
                <label for="email_address" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email_address" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />
                </div>
   </li>
```

Comment: You've tagged this jQuery and yet shown none.

Answer (score 1):

Remove required class on click of private and add required class on click of school.

Comment: I'd recommend to test this solution, should be the easiest one

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!! 
Solved this problem by adding jquery to submit button onclick

```
    onclick="if($('#address_type_private').is(':checked')) {jQuery('.school_field').remove();} else {jQuery('.priv_field').remove();}"
```

Comment: There is **never** a good reason to use inline JavaScript when you have jQuery at your disposal.  [See jQuery `.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)